# Bike Gears for maximum acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, estimation, biology

What should the sizes of the gears on my bicycle be to achieve the highest acceleration possible?

Comment: how is this acceleraton to be measured?

Comment: Here is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear). Just thought that it might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

For highest acceleration from a standstill, you need the smallest front chain ring and the largest rear sprocket possible. As soon as you get moving, however, you will need to change gears to a slightly smaller rear sprocket, and continue that process as you gain speed.

So the answer is that for *sustained* acceleration, you need the broadest possible size spread in both front and rear sprockets, and you must upshift every few seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

As Niels says, you need a very low gear but there are many practical complications.  What is your maximum pedalling rate?  There is no point in a gear so low that you cannot pedal fast enough to utilize it.  Also, although a change to a slightly higher gear would help once you gain some speed, you need to consider that you will be without power during the change.  An optimal gear configuration and usage could probably be determined but it would be highly dependent on you and your bike.  Your solution might be very different from mine.

You could compare with cars.  The same problem applies and a compromise is normally reached.  When I was young 4 gears were typical and some cars only had 3.  Now 5 is most common and 6 is becoming more common.  However, the changes may be more to do with economy than performance.  Motorcycles might closer, they are more often optimized for performance than economy.